# Space Leak on Gloss render of Mutable Image

Tags: haskell, concurrency, gloss, space-leak, juicy-pixels

I used the `JuicyPixel` library for generating a rendered image and the `gloss` library for a live preview.

The piece of code below causes a Space Leak

```hs
viewportRenderer :: Viewport Picture
viewportRenderer = do
  eventText <- Color [rgb|#FFFFFF|] . scale 0.1 0.1 . Text . show . _lastEvent <$> get

  viewportLoc' <- gets _viewportLoc
  viewportScale' <- gets _viewportScale
  image <- gets _renderedImage >>= unsafeFreezeImage
  let viewport =
        Color [rgb|#323232|] $
          unV2 translate viewportLoc' $
            join scale viewportScale' $
              fromImageRGBA8 image
  return (Pictures [viewport, eventText])
```

Some additional context:

```hs
type RenderedImage = MutableImage RealWorld PixelRGBA8
```

```hs
data ViewportState = ViewPortState
  { _lastEvent :: Event
  , _viewportScale :: !Float
  , _viewportOrigin :: V2 Float
  , _viewportLoc :: V2 Float
  , _repeatActions :: [(Event -> Bool, StateT ViewportState IO ())]
  -- ^ Actions that get repeated until (Event -> Bool) returns True
  , _renderedImage :: !RenderedImage
  }

makeLenses ''ViewportState

type Viewport a = StateT ViewportState IO a
-- Uses lazy StateT

initialViewPortState :: RenderedImage -> ViewportState
initialViewPortState image =
  ViewPortState
    { _lastEvent = EventResize (0, 0) -- Sentinel value
    , _viewportScale = 1
    , _viewportOrigin = 0
    , _viewportLoc = 0
    , _repeatActions = []
    , _renderedImage = image
    }
```

```hs
viewWindow :: RenderedImage -> IO ()
viewWindow !image = do
  playIO
    (InWindow "Reticule-Minor viewport" (400, 300) (100, 100))
    [rgb|#0B0B0B|]
    60
    (initialViewPortState image)
    (fmap fst . runStateT viewportRenderer)
    (\event -> fmap snd . runStateT (eventHandler event))
    (\t -> fmap snd . runStateT (timeHandler t))
```

```hs
renderer :: RenderedImage -> IO ()
renderer image = do
  forM_ [0..399] \x -> forM_ [0..299] \y -> do
    let r = floor @Float $ (fromIntegral x / 399) * 255
        g = floor @Float $ (fromIntegral y / 299) * 255
    writePixel image x y (PixelRGBA8 r g 255 255)
    threadDelay 10

main :: IO ()
main = do
  image <- createMutableImage 400 300 (PixelRGBA8 255 255 255 0) >>= newIORef
  _ <- forkIO $ renderer image
  V.viewWindow image
```

https://github.com/Perigord-Kleisli/reticule-minor
(Repo containing the whole codebase)

---

The idea is to have a `MutableImage` be continually written to by `renderer` forked in the background and to have `viewportRenderer` display the result every frame. Though as said, `viewportRenderer` causes a space leak. I'm wondering if this can be fixed by modifying Strictness or if I should probably utilize another Data Structure for passing the image.

I wouldnt really call it "best practice" but I don't really need to deal with having race conditions here.

- I've experimented on using `IORef RenderedImage` and `MVar RenderedImage` though both of these didn't fix the space leak.
- It was also unable to be optimized away by passing `-O2` as a compile option.
- I tried it with just generating a new image every frame and it didn't create a space leak. Unless I generate an image from the `RenderedImage`.
- I've read the image in both `freezeImage`, `unsafeFreezeImage` though both caused space leaks. (`unsafeFreezeImage` was faster and produced the same results which is strange as the library docs mention that you shouldnt be able to use the `MutableImage` after passing it)

Edit: I did some profiling which resulted in the following results.
[image: Heap Profile]

[image: Allocation report graph]

With the profiler output being:
https://pastebin.com/3YMFpAem

The results are admittedly quite surprising, with `createMutableImage` being responsible for most of the allocations.

Comment: The `createMutableImage` blue band might be the widest one, but its size remains largely constant at ~500k, which looks reasonable for a 400 x 300 image. The widening bands relevant to the leak are instead the white and pink ones.

Answer (score 4):

Solved the issue, apparently it's because the [gloss-juicy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-juicy) function I used continually cached the image each frame. It is implemented as:

```hs
fromImageRGBA8 :: Image PixelRGBA8 -> Picture
fromImageRGBA8 (Image { imageWidth = w, imageHeight = h, imageData = id }) =
  bitmapOfForeignPtr w h
                     (BitmapFormat TopToBottom PxRGBA)
                     ptr True
    where (ptr, _, _) = unsafeToForeignPtr id
```

So I just copied it and set [the `Bool` argument to `bitmapOfForeignPtr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.13.2.2/docs/Graphics-Gloss-Data-Bitmap.html#v:bitmapOfByteString) to `False`.

Comment: Nice find. Consider a patch.